# Numbers that are actually letters

Tags: code-golf, number, base-conversion, hexadecimal

Given a non-negative integer input, write a program that converts the number to hexadecimal and returns a truthy value if the hexadecimal form of the number contains only the characters `A` through `F` and a falsey value otherwise.

---

Test cases

```
10
==> True (A in hexadecimal)

100
==> False (64 in hexadecimal)

161
==> False (A1 in hexadecimal)

11259375
==> True (ABCDEF in hexadecimal)

0
==> False (0 in hexadecimal)
```

---

Bonus: **-40 bytes** if your program prints `Only letters` for the challenge described above, `Only numbers` if the hexadecimal version of the number only contains the digits `0-9` and `Mix` if the hexadecimal number contains at least one number and at least one letter.

---

This is code golf. Standard rules apply. Shortest code in bytes wins. Either functions or full programs are allowed.

Comment: Currently drafting an answer in Golfical.

Comment: My current idea: covert to base 16 string, then See if trying to parse that string as a base 10 number returns `NaN`

Comment: @Cyoce That may work, depending on your choice of language

Comment: Unrealistic bonus (once again): just the string `MixOnlynumbersletters` is 21 chars

Comment: Never mind, `a1` can't be parsed as base 10 either.

Comment: You say "positive integer input", but 0 is a test case.

Comment: @edc65 Pyth (and I) say [otherwise](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66468/20080).

Comment: @isaacg Pyth (and you) would have been at ease with the original -25 bonus (which I was referring to)? WIth a score of 18 instead of Adnan's 6

Comment: @edc65 Thanks, I didn't realise the original bonus was lower.

Comment: @SuperJedi224 Have you come up with a solution? Or have you already posted it and I missed it?

Comment: @Ampora Sorry about that. I kind of forgot.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Pyth, 43 - 40 = 3 bytes

```
?&K@J.HQG-JG"Mix"%"Only %sers"?K"lett""numb
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3F%26K%40J.HQG-JG%22Mix%22%25%22Only+%25sers%22%3FK%22lett%22%22numb&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=10%0A100%0A161%0A11259375%0A0&debug=0)

This achieves the bonus. `Only numbers` and `Only letters` fortunately only differ by 4 letters. printf-style formatting is used with `%`.

The selection system is done by both taking the intersection of the hex with `G`, the alphabet, and subtracting out `G`. If neither ends up falsy, it's a mix, while if the intersection is falsy, it's numbers, and if the subtraction is falsy, it's letters.

Comment: Damn this Pyth is weird. Would be very cool if you could get a negative score though.

Answer (score 16):

## Pyth, 6 bytes

```
!-.HQG

  .HQ   # Converts the input to hexadecimal
 -   G  # Deletes all letters
!       # If empty, output True, else False
```

Test it [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%21-.HQG&debug=0)

Answer (score 12):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
b16>9P
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=YjE2PjlQ&input=&args=MTEyNTkzNzU)

#### How it works

```
b16>9P  Input: z

b16     Convert the input to base 16.
   >9   Compare each resulting digit with 9; return 1 iff greater.
     P  Take the product of the resulting Booleans.
```

Comment: Isn't there a built in for 16 or is that not a thing?

Comment: There is now. This was one of the first Jelly answers...

Answer (score 12):

### Python, 24 bytes

```python
lambda n:min('%x'%n)>'9'
```

Converts the input a hex string (without `0x` prefix) with `'%x'%n`. Sees if all its chars are greater than `'9'` (which letters are) by seeing if the `min` is above `'9'`.

Comment: I don't know how Python handles characters / numbers, but the ASCII code of `'9'` is 54. So if you can write `...>54` you can save a byte.

Comment: @CompuChip Python doesn't treat chars or strings as numbers. In fact, Python 2 considers them to be greater than all numbers.

Answer (score 11):

## [TeaScript](https://github.com/vihanb/TeaScript), 11 bytes <s>13 15 16</s>

```
xT(16)O(Sz)
```

Pretty simple. This uses TeaScript 2.0. You can get this version from the Github

### Explanation

```
        // Implicit: x = input, Sz = alphabet
xT(16)  // input -> hex
O(Sz)   // Only letters?
```

[Try it online](http://vihanserver.tk/p/TeaScript/#?code=%22xT(16)O(Sz,1)%22&inputs=%5B%2210%22%5D&opts=%7B%22int%22:true,%22ar%22:false,%22debug%22:false,%22chars%22:false,%22html%22:false%7D) (slightly modified version that works on web)

Comment: Is the down-vote because this is long? Is there something else wrong with this answer that I'm not aware of? Or does someone just not personally like this answer?

Comment: I wouldn't say 16 or 13 bytes is long!

Comment: You have to admit that down-goating your posts is pretty tempting.

Answer (score 8):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 10

```
i16YA1Y2mA
```

#### Examples

```
>> matl i16YA1Y2mA
> 240
0
>> matl i16YA1Y2mA
> 255
1
```

#### Explanation

```
i       % input                         
16YA    % convert to string representation in base 16
1Y2     % predefined literal: 'A':'Z'
m       % true for set member             
A       % all
```

---

## Bonus challenge: 53−40 = 13

```
i16YA1Y2mXKA?'Only letters'}Ka?'Mix'}'Only numbers']]
```

#### Examples

```
>> matl
 > i16YA1Y2mXKA?'Only letters'}Ka?'Mix'}'Only numbers']]
 > 
> 255
Only letters

>> matl
 > i16YA1Y2mXKA?'Only letters'}Ka?'Mix'}'Only numbers']]
 > 
> 100
Only numbers

>> matl
 > i16YA1Y2mXKA?'Only letters'}Ka?'Mix'}'Only numbers']]
 > 
> 240
Mix
```

#### Explanation

```
i                       % input                                                 
16YA                    % convert integer to string representation in base 16
1Y2                     % predefined literal: 'A':'Z'
m                       % true for set member       
XK                      % copy to clipboard K                 
A                       % all                                   
?                       % if (top of the stack)                 
  'Only letters'        % string literal                                        
}                       % else                 
  K                     % paste from clipboard K      
  a                     % any                
  ?                     % if (top of the stack)      
    'Mix'               % string literal    
  }                     % else                                                  
    'Only numbers'      % string literal           
  ]                     % end             
]                       % end
```

Comment: hmmm what is that ? seems like matlab got some nuc power now !

Comment: @Agawa001 Hahaha. [Sort of](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL)

Answer (score 8):

## Python 3, <s>30</s> 29 bytes

1 byte stripped thanks to [sysreq](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/46231/sysreq) and Python 3.

```python
lambda n:hex(n)[2:].isalpha()
```

Simple `lambda` and slicing.

Comment: [27 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKk2pOs8qolZJL7M4MacgI1FD839BUWZeiUaahqmmJheMbWigqfkfAA "Python 3 – Try It Online") using a format string literal

Answer (score 8):

## LabVIEW, 52-40 = 12 [LabVIEW Primitives](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7589/39490)

Praise the built-ins!

[image]

Answer (score 8):

## C, <s>46</s> <s>43</s> 37 bytes

Now with more recursion! (Thanks Dennis):

```c
F(x){return(x%16>9)*(x<16?:F(x/16));}
```

Bonus: even shorter (33 bytes), but fails for `x = 0`:

```c
F(x){return!x?:(x%16>9)*F(x/16);}
```

---

```c
b;F(x){for(b=x;x;x/=16)b*=x%16>9;return b;}
```

`F()` takes an `int` and returns either `0` (false) or non-zero (true).

I didn't even try to achieve the bonus, `"MixOnly lettersnumbers"` takes 23 bytes alone, tracking the new condition would have required 9 additional bytes, `printf()` is 8 bytes, which adds up to 40, nullifying the effort.

Test main:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int testdata[] = {10, 100, 161, 11259375, 0};
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    int d = testdata[i];
    printf("%d (0x%x) -> %s\n", d, d, F(d)?"yep":"nope");
  }
}
```

Comment: What's `?:`? I had to replace it with `||` to get it to compile. Also, can you save a byte by replacing the `*` with an `&` thus avoiding the `()`s on the left (although you then have to add a space)?

Comment: @Neil `a?:b` is a GNU extension that evaluates to `a` if `a` is a truthy value, otherwise to `b`. Comes handy to handle null pointers like `send(message ?: "(no message)");`. I know it's not portable, but code portability is never a concern in code golf :)

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo you can get this down to `33` bytes by doing this: `F(x){x=(x%16>9)*(x<16?:F(x/16));}` this abuses a (GCC) bug where if there is no return variable in a function and the main argument was set, it will auto-return the main-argument in some cases (based on what logic was done), and this happens to be one of those cases! Try it online: http://bit.ly/2pR52UH

Answer (score 7):

### Mathematica, 32 bytes

```
Tr@DigitCount[#,16,0~Range~9]<1&
```

Explanation:

```
                               &   A function returning whether
Tr@                                 the sum of elements of
   DigitCount[ ,  ,         ]        the numbers of
                   0~Range~9          zeros, ones, ..., nines in
                16                    the hexadecimal expansion of
              #                       the first argument
                             <1     is less than one.
```

Answer (score 7):

## Julia, 18 bytes

```julia
n->isalpha(hex(n))
```

This is an anonymous function that accepts an integer and returns a boolean. To call it, give it a name, e.g. `f=n->...`.

The input is converted to a hexadecimal string using `hex`, then we check whether its entirely comprised of alphabetic characters using `isalpha`.

Answer (score 7):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 18 bytes

```perl6
{.base(16)!~~/\d/} # 18 bytes
```

usage:

```perl6
# give it a name
my &code = {.base(16)!~~/\d/}

for 10, 100, 161, 11259375, 0 {
  printf "%8s %6s %s\n", $_, .base(16), .&code
}

      10      A True
     100     64 False
     161     A1 False
11259375 ABCDEF True
       0      0 False
```

Answer (score 7):

## Javascript, ES6, no regexp, 28 bytes

```js
F=n=>n%16>9&&(n<16||F(n>>4))
```

There's also this 27-byte version but it returns the inverse value.

```js
F=n=>n%16<10||n>15&&F(n>>4)
```

Comment: Nice! You could also rearrange it like this for 23 bytes: `F=n=>!n||n%16>9&F(n>>4)`

Comment: @user81655 - Unfortunately, that version returns true for 0, so it's incorrect.

Comment: Oh right, I guess the shortest would be `F=n=>n%16>9&&n<16|F(n>>4)` then.

Comment: @user81655 I'm pretty sure you need to short-circuit the `||`, but I think you could get away with using `&` instead of `&&` in that case.

Comment: @Neil Why's that? Did you test it?

Comment: @user81655 OK so thinking about it again it doesn't matter which of the two operators short-circuits as long as one of them does. Sorry for the confusion. (I should really avoid commenting after midnight...)

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript ES6, 29

No bonus

```js
n=>!/\d/.test(n.toString(16))
```

With the new value of **-40** the bonus is nearer now ... but not enough. Bonus score 70 <s>71</s> - 40 => **30 <s>31</s>**

```js
n=>/\d/.test(n=n.toString(16))?1/n?'Only numbers':'Mix':'Only letters'
```

Test snippet (type a number inside the input box)

```css
#I { width:50%}
```

```html
<input id=I oninput="test()"/><br>
Hex <span id=H></span><br>
Result <span id=R></span>
```

Comment: `-n-1`=`~n`, right?

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy if n is not numeric like 'A' (that's the whole point in this challenge), `~n == -1` while `-n-1 == NaN`

Answer (score 4):

## [GS2](http://github.com/nooodl/gs2), 6 bytes

```
V↔i/◙s
```

The source code uses the CP437 encoding. [Try it online!](http://gs2.tryitonline.net/#code=VuKGlGkv4peZcw&input=MTEyNTkzNzU)

#### How it works

```
V       Evaluate the input.
 ↔      Push 16.
  i     Perform base conversion.
   /    Sort.
    ◙   Push [10].
     s  Perform greater-or-equal comparison.
```

Answer (score 4):

## Java, <s>46</s> <s>44</s> 38 bytes

```java
i->i.toHexString(i).matches("[a-f]+");
```

Pretty simple one-liner that converts the integer to a hexadecimal string and uses regex to determine if all characters are letters.

-2 bytes thanks to @Eng.Fouad.

Comment: `"[a-f]+"` would save 2 bytes.

Comment: Fails for 516..

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy [No it doesn't.](http://ideone.com/OlZd3C)

Comment: Well now it determines if the string contains _a_ hex letter, so remove the `+`–it's a waste of byte.

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy [No.](http://ideone.com/kEVEfO) `matches` returns true if the entire string can be matched by the given regex. `[a-f]` without the plus sign is incorrect since it doesn't match the *entire* string given that it contains more than one character; it would if and only if one valid character is present.

Comment: Oh right. Ok then.

Answer (score 4):

## Octave, 22 bytes

```
@(n)all(dec2hex(n)>64)
```

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 19 bytes

```
->n{!('%x'%n)[/\d/]}
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
-> n {
  !('%x'%n)[/\d/]
}
```

**Usage:**

```
f=->n{!('%x'%n)[/\d/]} # Assigning it to a variable
f[0]
=> false
f[10]
=> true
f[100]
=> false
f[161]
=> false
f[11259375]
=> true
```

**With bonus, 70 - 40 = 30 bytes**

```
->n{'%x'%n=~/^(\d+)|(\D+)$/;$1?'Only numbers':$2?'Only letters':'Mix'}
```

**Usage:**

```
f=->n{'%x'%n=~/^(\d+)|(\D+)$/;$1?'Only numbers':$2?'Only letters':'Mix'}
f[10]
=> Only letters
f[100]
=> Only numbers
f[161]
=> Mix
```

Comment: Late, but `'%x'%n!~/\d/` is a shorter check for solution one, and solution two has a raw byte count of 70, not 75.

Answer (score 3):

### CJam (<strike>9</strike> 8 bytes)

```
{GbA,&!}
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%7BGbA%2C%26!%7D%0A%0A%5B10%20100%20161%2011259375%200%5D%25%60)

Comment: Equally short: `{Gb$N<!}`

Answer (score 3):

### Perl, 69 - 40 = 29 bytes

```perl
$_=sprintf"%X",<>;print s/\d//?$_?"Mix":"Only numbers":"Only letters"
```

Answer (score 2):

## SmileBASIC 3.2.1, 78 bytes

```
INPUT V FOR I=0 TO 9
IF INSTR(HEX$(V),STR$(I))>-1 THEN ?"FALSE"END
NEXT?"TRUE"
```

Comment: I don't see any non-ASCII characters here (unless there are some); [this counter](http://mother-eff.in/byte-counter) is the definitive decider and it says `81`.

Comment: It doesn't matter that the implementation uses UTF-16 internally; to the rest of the world they may as well be UTF-8 chars in the range `0-127`, thus your byte count is `81`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, wasn't sure if "bytes" meant I should count 2 per char. 81 it is.

Comment: Actually, the current +10/-0 [consensus](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7248/should-a-character-encoding-that-cant-actually-be-used-by-a-compiler-interprete) (which, by the way, I now disagree with) is that we must always use the encoding that an interpreter uses. If you disagree, please post a dissenting opinion on that question.

Comment: @ThomasKwa pfft, okay, oops, now I know better. I didn't realise there was a consensus about that, and I spend a fair bit of time on meta.

Comment: Can you not save 3 bytes by writing the entire conditional inside the `IF` statement?

Comment: @Neil Ah, you are indeed right. I'll fix that (as well as fixing my byte count.)

Comment: @lirtosiast, I created a meta post asking how to score SmileBASIC [here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11147/62670).

Answer (score 2):

### Ceylon, 55 bytes

```ceylon
Boolean l(Integer n)=>!any(formatInteger(n,16)*.digit);
```

Straightforward ... we format `n` as a hexadecimal number (which produces a string), call on each character of that string the `.digit` number (which returns true if it is a digit), then check whether any of them are true, then negate this.

The version with bonus has a lot higher score of **119 - 25 = 94**:

```ceylon
String c(Integer n)=>let(s=formatInteger(n),d=s*.digit)(every(d)then"Only numbers"else(any(d)then"Mix"else"Only letters"));
```

<sub>I'm not sure how anyone could make a bonus version short enough to be better than the no-bonus version, even those strings alone have length 28 together. Maybe a language which makes it really hard to produce a truthy/falsey value.</sub>

Here is a formatted version:

```ceylon
String c(Integer n) =>
        let (d = formatInteger(n,16)*.digit)
    (every(d) then "Only numbers"
                else (any(d) then "Mix"
                    else "Only letters"));
```

Answer (score 2):

### Seriously, 12 bytes

```
4ª,¡OkúOkd-Y
```

Hex Dump:

```
34a62cad4f6b
a34f6b642d59
```

[Try It Online](http://seriouslylang.herokuapp.com/link/code=34a62cad4f6ba34f6b642d59&input=255)

It's the same as the other stack language answers. It would be only 7 bytes if Seriously supported string subtraction yet.

EDIT: Seriously now supports string subtraction and the following 7 byte solution now works:

```
ú4╙,¡-Y
```

Hex Dump:

```
a334d32cad2d59
```

[Try It Online](http://seriouslylang.herokuapp.com/link/code=a334d32cad2d59&input=100)

Comment: 11: `4╙,¡#S;ú∩S=` (or `4ª` or `8τ`, lots of ways to spell `:16:` in two bytes :P)

Comment: I didn't know S I think.

Answer (score 2):

### Rust, 70 bytes

```rust
fn f(n:i32)->bool{format!("{:x}",n).chars().all(|c|c.is_alphabetic())}
```

Because, ya know, <s>Java</s> Rust.

It's actually quite elegant, though:

```rust
format!("{:x}", n)         // format n as hex (:x)
  .chars()                 // get an Iter over the characters
  .all(                    // do all Iter elements satisfy the closure?
    |c| c.is_alphabetic()  // self-explanatory
  )
```

But it's a shame the function definition boilerplate is so long.... :P

Comment: I have an idea. More closures!

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 44 bytes - 40 bonus = 4 bytes

```
2,riGbAf/&:-"Only numbersOnly lettersMix"C/=
```

[Try it here~](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=2%2CriGbAf%2F%26%3A-%22Only%20numbersOnly%20lettersMix%22C%2F%3D&input=10)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

Code:

```
ha
```

Ha! That is two bytes! <s>Sadly non-competing because this language postdates the challenge :(</s>

Explanation:

```
h   # Convert input to hexadecimal
 a  # is_alpha, checks if the value only contains letters
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=aGE&input=MTEyNTkzNzU) or [Verify all test cases!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=W0lExb0KCj8iIHlpZWxkcyAiP2hhLAoKXQ&input=MTAKMTAwCjE2MQoxMTI1OTM3NQow)

Comment: `hdÔ©1åi•4?ŸâÏ„Î›•}®0åi•4?ŸàpÕTà•}®g2Qi•²`•}36B` for the bonus resulting in... 6 more! Wooooo bonuses!

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 16 bytes

```
->n{/\d/!~'%x'%n}
```

## Ruby, 70 bytes - 40 bonus = 30

```
f=->n{s="Only #{n%16<10?:Numbers:'Letters'}";n<16||s==f[n/16]?s:'Mix'}
```

Comment: Amazingly, the other Ruby poster miscounted their solution w/ bonus and they also have 30 as their final score. But hey, it's a different and unique solution!

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 28 bytes

```python
lambda x:min(hex(x)[1:])>'@'
```

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, 40 bytes

```
(every'alpha-char-p(format()"~x"(read)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JLC74r1FQlJmX/F8jtSy1qFI9MacgI1E3OSOxSLdAIy2/KDexRENTqa5CSaMoNTFFU1Pzv@Z/QzNDAA)

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, <s>56</s> 44 bytes

This isn't going to win, but might as well. Takes one [command-line argument](https://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php).

Thank you @Blackhole for reducing this by 12 bytes.

```php
<?=ctype_lower(base_convert($argv[1],10,16))

// Previous attempt, 56 bytes
<?=preg_match('#^[a-f]+$#',base_convert($argv[1],10,16))
```

Comment: I'm pleased to introduce you the [`ctype_alpha()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/function.ctype-alpha.php) function ;).

Comment: @Blackhole Ahh thank you. Gotta love PHP, functions for everything :)

Comment: [`dechex()`](http://php.net/dechex) saves 11 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 12 bytes

```
!UsG r"[a-f]
```

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=IVVzRyByIlthLWZd&input=MTEyNTkzNzU=)

#### How it works

```
!UsG r"[a-f] // Implicit: U = input integer, G = 16
 UsG         // Convert U to a base-16 string.
     r"[a-f] // Replace all lowercase letters with an empty string.
!            // Take the logical NOT of the result.
             // This returns true for an empty string; false for anything else.
```

Comment: I think `!!UsG r"\\d` might work and save a byte

Comment: @Downgoat Good observation, but that returns true for *any* number that contains a letter.

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 39 bytes

```hs
p n|mod n 16<10=0|n<16=1|1<2=p$div n 16
```

Returns `0` or `1`. Usage example:

```hs
*Main> map p [10,100,161,11259375,0]
[1,0,0,1,0]
```

Haskell has neither built-in base conversion nor check for letters. Both functions are in modules where the imports alone would cost 36 bytes, so that's not an option. Instead I check the input number `n` for:

1. if `mod n 16` is less than `10` -> False
2. if `n` is less than `16` -> True
3. otherwise re-check with `n/16`.

Answer (score 1):

## C, 132 bytes

```c
int main(){int a=0,p=1;char b[256];scanf("%d",&a);sprintf(b,"%x",a);for(char*c=b;*c!='\0';c++)if(isdigit(*c)){printf("False");p=0;}if(p)printf("True");return 0;}
```

**Detailed**

```c
int main()
{
    int a=0, p=1;
    char b [256];

    scanf("%d",&a); // read input as an integer
    sprintf(b,"%x",a); // read in Hex into string

    for(char * c=b; *c!='\0'; c++)
    {
        if(isdigit(*c)) // if it's a digit
        {
            printf("%x No",a);
            p=0;
        }
    }

    if(p) // if no digit was found
    {
        printf("%x Yes",a);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Bonus, 232 - 40 = 192 bytes**

```c
int main(){int a=0, p=0,q=0;char b [256];scanf("%d",&a);sprintf(b,"%x",a);for(char * c=b; *c!='\0'; c++) if(isdigit(*c)) p=1; else q=1;if(p&&q) printf("Mixed");else if(p) printf("Only numbers");else printf("Only letters");return 0;}
```

**Detailed**

```c
int main()
{
    int a=0, p=0,q=0;
    char b [256];

    scanf("%d",&a);
    sprintf(b,"%x",a);

    for(char * c=b; *c!='\0'; c++) if(isdigit(*c)) p=1; else q=1;

    if(p&&q) printf("Mixed");
    else if(p) printf("Only numbers");
    else printf("Only letters");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `main()` does not return `void` in standard C.

Comment: @Peter fixed it now, it's weird given I've read it in a book during my study. C89 turned out that you can write `main()` and the return type will be assumed as `int`

Answer (score 1):

## Gema, 41 characters

```
*=@c{@radix{10;16;*}}
c:<D>=f@end;?=;\Z=t
```

There is no boolean in Gema, so it simply outputs “t” or “f”.

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ echo -n '11259375' | gema '*=@c{@radix{10;16;*}};c:<D>=f@end;?=;\Z=t'
t
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 24 bytes

```perl
$_=sprintf"%x",$_;$_=/\D/&/\d/?Mix:Only.$".(/\d/?numb:lett).ers
```

Code is 63 bytes, add 1 for the `-p` flag, and then subtract 40 for the bonus.

Answer (score 1):

## Binary-Encoded Golfical, 50+1 (`-x` flag)=51 bytes

Noncompeting; the modulo instruction used here, although it was added to the specs, according the repo's revision history, on the same day this question was posted, was for some reason never implemented until earlier today.

Hexdump:

```
00 C0 03 15 14 14 1B 1A 14 08 01 14 17 00 10 14
00 01 0A 01 21 1E 2C 3D 14 53 2D 14 08 01 0A 01
1C 00 0A 00 10 17 0A 01 08 01 00 00 26 14 1E 1C
1D 14
```

This encoding can be converted back to the original graphical form using the included Encoder utility, or run directly by adding the `-x` flag.

Original image:

[image]

Magnified 50x:

[image]

Rough translation:

```
prompt *p
label A
push *p
*p%=16
if *p<10
 print 0
 exit
endif
*p=pop
*p/=16
if *p==0
 print 1
 exit
endif
goto A
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 32 bytes

<sub>since [rink.attendant.6](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66437/55735) won´t react; I post my own.</sub>

```php
echo+ctype_alpha(dechex($argn));
```

takes input from STDIN; prints `1` or `0`; run with `-R`.

**bonus attempt, <s>93</s> 87-40=47**
<sub>5 bytes saved by Jörg, 1 by me</sub>

```php
echo(ctype_alpha($s=dechex($argn))+$d=ctype_digit($s))?"Only ".[lett,numb][$d].ers:Mix;
```

takes input from STDIN; run with `-nR`.

btw. `ctype_xdigit` would be an option for `Mix` and help serialize (though `pi` is the shortest alternative); but I guess it can´t get any shorter than Jörgs idea with my golfing.
The more you serialize, the longer it gets.

a **partly serialized** version for <s>101</s> 100-40=60:
<sub>2 bytes saved and 1 byte fixed by Jörg</sub>

```php
echo strtr([ctype_alpha($s=dechex($argn))=>_letters,ctype_digit($s)=>_numbers,Mix][1],[_=>"Only "]);
```

and **fully serialized** for <s>114</s> 112-40=72:
<sub>-2 bytes inspired by Jörg</sub>

```php
foreach([pi=>Mix,ctype_alpha=>lett,is_numeric=>numb]as$f=>$t)$f(dechex($argn))&&$s=$t<a?$t:"Only $t".ers;echo$s;
```

Comment: wonderful I found a shorter approach `echo ctype_alpha($s=dechex($argn))+($d=ctype_digit($s))?"Only ".[lett,numb][$d].ers:Mix;` or `echo ctype_alpha($s=dechex($argn))+($d=ctype_digit($s))?$d?"Only numbers":"Only letters":Mix;` with the same byte count for the bonus version

Comment: @JörgHülsermann Thanks. And another byte shorter if you place the parentheses differently.

Comment: I found your old version  more interesting! And you can save two Bytes if you change the order `echo[ctype_alpha($s=dechex($argn))=>"Only letters",ctype_digit($s)=>"Only numbers",Mix][1];`  Could you please add your old version as tip for PHP. And please add a closing `]` in the partly serialized version

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 30 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md) - 40 = -10

```
ḤDA?‘Ṇß ɱṀ‘ʂ:dAS?ʋMix:‘Ṇß ḶẸ‘ʂ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCOCVBNERBJTNGJUUyJTgwJTk4JUUxJUI5JTg2JUMzJTlGJTIwJUM5JUIxJUUxJUI5JTgwJUUyJTgwJTk4JUNBJTgyJTNBZEFTJTNGJUNBJThCTWl4JTNBJUUyJTgwJTk4JUUxJUI5JTg2JUMzJTlGJTIwJUUxJUI4JUI2JUUxJUJBJUI4JUUyJTgwJTk4JUNBJTgyJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9MTAmZmxhZ3M9)

### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ḤA
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCOCVBNEEmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0xMCZmbGFncz0=)

##### Explanation

```python
Ḥ               # Convert to hexadecimal
 D              # Duplicate it
  A             # Is it all alphabetic?
   ?            # If it is:
    ‘Ṇß ɱṀ‘ʂ    #  Push compressed string "Only letters"
            :   # Otherwise:
             dA #  Check if each character is alphabetic
S?              #  If at least one is true:
  ʋMix          #   Push the string "Mix"
      :         #  Otherwise:
       ‘Ṇß ḶẸ‘ʂ #   Push compressed string "Only numbers"
```

```python
Ḥ   # Convert to hexadecimal
 A  # Is it all alphabetic?
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 5.9, <s>61</s> <s>58</s> 51 bytes

```swift
let l={String($0+0,radix:16).allSatisfy(\.isCased)}
```

I chose to use `isCased` rather than `isLetter` in order to save a byte.

Answer (score 0):

### CoffeeScript, <s>42</s> 36 bytes

```coffee
f=(x)->/^[a-f]+$/.test x.toString 16

// Previous attempt (42)
f=(x)->!x.toString(16).replace /[a-f]/g,''
```

---

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>41</s> 36 bytes

```js
f=x=>/^[a-f]+$/.test(x.toString(16))

// Previous attempt (41)
f=x=>!x.toString(16).replace(/[a-f]/g,``)
```

Comment: You can remove the `f=` from the javascript one.

Answer (score 0):

## R, 34 bytes

```
!grepl("\\d",sprintf("%x",scan()))
```

`scan()` takes an integer from stdin, `sprintf("%x",...)` returns the hexadecimal representation of that integer (R's `sprintf` is equivalent to C's `sprintf`), then the regex checks if the string contains digits.

Usage:

```
> !grepl("\\d",sprintf("%x",scan()))
1: 100
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] FALSE
> !grepl("\\d",sprintf("%x",scan()))
1: 10
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] TRUE
> !grepl("\\d",sprintf("%x",scan()))
1: 161
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] FALSE
> !grepl("\\d",sprintf("%x",scan()))
1: 11259375
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] TRUE
> !grepl("\\d",sprintf("%x",scan()))
1: 0
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

## , 9 chars / 16 bytes

```
!ïⓧċ/[α]⌿
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter.html?eval=true&input=10&code=!%C3%AF%E2%93%A7%C4%8B%2F%5B%CE%B1%5D%E2%8C%BF)</kbd>

Regex aliases ftw!

## Explanation

```
        // Implicit: ï = input
!       // logical-negate the result of the following code:
 ïⓧ    // convert ï to hex...
 ċ/[α]⌿ // and see if it has any letters
        // implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 6 bytes

```
b16G-!
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=b16G-%21&input=255)

Or 10 bytes with the bonus

```
b16\9L>]0}DlRs*"Only numbers,Only letters,Mix"\,c@
```

Explanation:

```
b16                                                -      base_16(input())
   \9L<                                            -     map("9">char for char in ^)
       ]0                                          -    list(^)
         }                                         -   set(^)
          DlRs*                                    -  len(^)*sum(^)
                                                 @ - V[^]
               "Only numbers,Only letters,Mix"\,c  -  str.split(",")
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=b16%5C9L%3E%5D0%7DDlRs%2a%22Only+numbers%2COnly+letters%2CMix%22%5C%2Cc%40&input=270)

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, <s>52</s> 50 bytes

```
INPUT V
H$=HEX$(V)WHILE""<H$P=@A<POP(H$)||P
WEND?P
```

Determines if each digit is a number or letter by comparing it with `@A` (the A doesn't matter since it would only look at it if the first characters were the same). `@` is between the number and the letters in ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

## MATL, 7 bytes

```
1YAtk=~
```

Explanation:

```
1       % number literal
YA      % convert integer to string representation in given base (16)
t       % duplicate elements
k       % convert (the second) string to lowercase
=       % is equal?
~       % logical 'not' (element-wise)
        % (implicit) convert to string and display
```

For only letters to be in the base-16 representation, when the string is made lowercase every character must have changed, so the arrays should never be equal to each other, and only arrays of ones are truthy in MATL.

## Bonus challenge, 47-40 = 7 bytes:

```
1YAtk=XK?'Only numbers'}Ka?'Mix'}'Only letters'
```

Essentially the same as the other MATL answer given, the same ending was used just without trailing `]]` and with reordering the outputs.

Answer (score 0):

## Befunge ([quirkster flavor](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/befunge.html)), 34 bytes

```
&:44*%9`!#@ #. #0_44*/:!#@ #. #1_#
```

Befunge control flow loops around to the beginning when it hits the end, so a recursive solution is pretty natural. If the input is less than 9 modulo 16, print 0 (the only falsey value in Befunge) and exit. If not, divide the number by 16, rounding down. If it's now 0, print 1 and exit, otherwise recurse. In effect, this checks each hex digit from right to left.

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 35 bytes

```
#(every?(set"abcdef")(format"%x"%))
```

Answer (score 0):

## tcl, 35

```
puts [string is alp [format %x $n]]
```

[demo](http://rextester.com/IIY33455)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 16 bytes

```
$&16%v16/;OKT)P#
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/19FzdBMtczQTN/a3ztEM0D5////hoZGppbG5qYA)**

Essentially calculates all digits as numbers `0-16`, and then checks they are all over 10.

```
                    \ Implicit: Input on first stack
$        ;          \ While input != 0:
 &16%v              \   Push input % 16 to second stack
      16/           \   Floordiv input by 16
          O         \ Go to second stack
           KT)      \ Map all numbers to boolean: bigger than 10?
              P     \ Get the product (only 1 if all values are 1)
               #    \ Print result.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 121 bytes

```
=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(DEC2HEX(A2),"A",),"B",),"C",),"D",),"E",),"F",))=0
```

Nothing graceful about this one.

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 32 bytes

```scala
_.toHexString.forall(_.isLetter)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XY3BCoJAGITvPsWPp11IKbqEYFCngjpFpxD5s10xtl1Z_8oQn6SLHeoRehffJtFblxnmm4F5fooEFU6_B9cTZa4w0-7I9bS5o9Vu1FbmeBYJwbYroHIATkLCpQsMbVoEsLAWH4cd2UynEQ9grzOCsF8C5B0lpZlkE87_ybhHtdPJDRXIANhaUzhfGqMEag7h-0rSm7UQ-2RWohxOfGksKsViPys2gkhYPuxe9eBNM_gP)