# Find The Rank Of A Word

Tags: code-golf, string, combinatorics, sorting, permutations

### Definition

The rank of a word is defined as the position of the word when all the possible permutations (or arrangements) of its letters are arranged alphabetically, like in a dictionary, no matter if the words are meaningful or not.

Let us consider these two words - "blue" and "seen". To begin with, we would write all the possible arrangements of the letters of these words in alphabetical order:

```
"blue": "belu","beul","bleu","blue","buel","bule","eblu","ebul","elub","elbu","eubl",
        "eulb","lbeu","lbue","lebu","leub","lube","lueb","ubel","uble","uebl","uelb",
        "ulbe","uleb"
"seen": "eens","eesn","enes","ense","esen","esne","nees","nese","nsee","seen",
        "sene","snee"
```

Now let's look from the left and find the position of the words we need. We see that the word "blue" is at the 4th position and "seen" is at 10th position. So the rank of the word "blue" is 4, and that of "seen" is 10. This is the general way of calculating the rank of a word. Make sure you start counting from 1 only.

### Task

Your task is to write a code to take any word as an input and display its rank. The rank should be the output.
Be careful about words containing repeated letters.

### Examples

```
"prime" -> 94

"super" -> 93

"bless" -> 4

"speech" -> 354

"earth" -> 28

"a" -> 1

"abcd" -> 1

"baa" -> 3
```

You can assume the input to be completely in lowercase and the input will only contain **alphabetical characters**. Also if a blank space or an invalid string is entered, you may return anything.

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) , so the shortest code wins!

Comment: [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/34807/8478)

Comment: "Make sure you start counting from 1 only." - It's totally up to you to have this requirement, but do note that it's quite common to allow either 0 or 1 based indexing for such challenges.

Comment: Yeah ikr but if you start from 0 then you actually aren't displaying the original rank which is why I decided to add this requirement.

Comment: [Useful link](https://szkopul.edu.pl/problemset/problem/etwe8b5zlM4uVn4dpxr32ua8/site/?key=statement). You will get AC if your program runs in time `O(n log n)` or less. (sorry, no Python) My submission (C++) takes 2.53s to solve test 14.

Comment: Can I do a tuple or a list with that word, e.g. `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']` as opposed to  `'hello'`?

Comment: @user202729 AC?

Comment: @haneefmubarak "accepted". Commonly-known verdict on competitive programming online judge sites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 4 bytes

```
fuȯI
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/P630xHrP//@LC1JTkzMA)

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 71 bytes

```python
lambda s:sum(t<=(*s,)for t in{*permutations(s)})
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY27DoMwDEXn8hXekiA6IXWISr@kS4BERCIP2WaoEN@ehizW8dU9dv7xluJYHEzwLbsJ82qANB1B8nuSPQ3KJQQGH88@WwwHG/YpkiR1qc5hCuDZIqe0E/iQE3JfbqVuEURGH6wYQNBR7Rvm3RK1JFu7bDdZg9zAtDEvaysaI3T3qBciSydO0q8Lnh84Xf2tx0uo8gc)

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
œêsk>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//6OTDq4qz7f7/T8pJLS4GAA)
or as a [Test suite](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9TVln5/@jkw6uKs@3@Vyod3m@lcHi/ks7/gqLM3FSu4tKC1CKupJzU4mKu4oLU1OQMrtTEopIMrkSuxKTkFK6kxEQA)

**Explanation**

```
œ       # get permutations of input
 ê      # sort and remove duplicates
  s     # swap input to top of stack
   k    # get index of input in the list
    >   # increment
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 6 bytes

```
hxS{.p
```

**[Test suite.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=hxS%7B.p&input=%22earth%22&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22prime%22%0A%22super%22%0A%22bless%22%0A%22speech%22%0A%22earth%22%0A%22a%22%0A%22abcd%22%0A%22baa%22&debug=0)**

### Explanation

```
hxS{.p || Full program.

    .p || All the permutations of the input.
   {   || Deduplicate.
  S    || Sort.
 x     || Index of the input into this list.
h      || Increment.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
Œ!ṢQi
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJMWHOxcFZv7//1@puCA1NTlDCQA) or see the **[test suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJMWHOxcFZv4/uudw@6OmNVlA/KhhjoKuncKjhrmR//9HKxUUZeamKulwKRWXFqQWgRhJOanFxWCRgtTU5AwQKzWxqATMSAQTSckpYIWJiUqxAA)**

### How it works

```
Œ!ṢQi - Main link. Argument: s (string)      e.g. 'baa'
Œ!    - All permutations                          ['baa', 'baa', 'aba', 'aab', 'aba', 'aab']
  Ṣ   - Sort                                      ['aab', 'aab', 'aba', 'aba', 'baa', 'baa']
   Q  - Deduplicate                               ['aab', 'aba', 'baa']
    i - 1-based index of s                        3
```

Comment: Fails for words containing repeated letters.

Comment: @ManishKundu and Xcoder, fixed

Comment: Unfortunately `Œ¿` doesn't work.

Comment: Does `ṢŒ¿` work?

Comment: @EsolangingFruit No, that just outputs `1`

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 78 bytes

```python
lambda s:-~sorted(set(permutations(s))).index(tuple(s))
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdDNSsUwEAXgfZ5i6CoVLNpewXuhr@ATuEnbKQ00P8xMQDe@eo00YMS7/c7JcEj8lC34/ljH92M3bloM8O3xiwMJLppRdERySYzY4Flz27ad9Qt@aElxxx9QKwUHVpAkhJ3BuphfPxyGOROsupn2hE0L4wgX9auM6E99flKVR7Ku1K9/@ilPKT6o@joy3zkfEeft9OGlTtCQlKB/rdyUNTVN8/JfJ1Oqg1J5rRdo3gKcef4mQKJA3DXHNw)

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 73 bytes

- Thanks to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder) for choosing Python 3; saving five bytes.

```python
lambda s:-~sorted({*permutations(s)}).index((*s,))
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdBNCsIwEAXgfU4RukqKFrUKKvQKnsBNaqcYaH6YSUERvXoNNGBEt997GR7x93B1tp765jwNyrSd4nRcvshhgE48Sg9oxqCCdpYEyaestO3gJkRJCylZj85wHQCDcwNxbXx8WE6KKBLvRdEOIxSSNw3fso8SgJ11vWKZe9Qm1Q9f/THuSF6z/DoQ/TnvAS7X2etdnoDCkILNPnOV1uTUXrpfbVWq1ozFtTaI4uT4nMc/4oDokKpCTm8)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 56 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
elemIndex<*>([]:).nub.sort.permutations
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYyxDoMwDER3vsLKBFWVD6hKpy6VyhcgBgeMiJqEKDZS/z6NOpCb7t3ZtyF/yLmcrY97EniioH5blmbtyZF/hYW@98ujHadbp8NhNJczHSn5Q1DsHjh7tAF68BgHaGOyQUDD2kEDRSOoEnlSf7qC4qM8n2QcMdcuEs3biYRJKmF1Zl7qAqKCKf8A)

+6 bytes because of 1-indexing requirement. :(

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 8 bytes

```
q_e!\a#)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/vzA@VTEmUVnz///igtTU5AwA)

+1 byte due to 1-indexed requirement.

Comment: Just got the exact same answer :(

Comment: @EsolangingFruit You can still post it if you want :-)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>8</s> 10 bytes

<s>0-indexed.</s> Poxy, unnecessary 1-indexing, increasing my byte count by 25%!

```
á â n bU Ä
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=4SDiIG4gYlUgxA==&input=InNwZWVjaCI=)

---

### Explanation

`á` gets all the permutations of the input, `â` removes duplicates, `n` sorts them and `b` gets the index of the first occurrence of the input, `U`.

Comment: Note the (unusual) "Make sure you start counting from 1 only" requirement. I have commented under the OP that it would be normal to allow 0-based too.

Comment: Ah, goddamnit; stoopid 1-indexing. Will update shortly but it'll up my byte count by 25%.

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
S€(OuP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/hR0xoN/9KA////KyUlJioBAA) I feel like there should be a way to drop `(`.

**Explanation:**

```
 €     -- return index of the input 
S (    -- in the list generated by applying the following functions to the input:
     P -- permutations
    u  -- remove duplicates
   O   -- sort
```

Comment: [Bracket removed (-1 byte)](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HTGv/SgEM7////r5SUmKgEAA "Husk – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <strike>28</strike> 23 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to FrownyFrog

```
1+/:~@~.@(A.~i.@!@#)i.]
```

### How it works?

```
                      ] - the argument
         (A.~      )    - permutations in the 
             i.@!@#     - range 0 to factorial of the arg. length
  /:~@~.@               - remove duplicates and sort
                    i.  - index of arg. in the sorted list
1+                      - add 1 (for 1-based indexing)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DbX1reoc6vQcNBz16jL1HBQdlDUz9WL/a3JxpSZn5CukKagXFGXmpqorKMAFiksLUouQBZJyUouLUVQUpAKZyCKpiUUlQAEY31DBUEU9EcFXT0xKTkHiJiUCJcHgPwA)

Comment: 23: `1+/:~@~.@(A.~i.@!@#)i.]`

Comment: @FrownyFrog - Good use of i. for finding the index! Thanks!

Comment: The TIO link is still the old version :)

Comment: @Conor O'Brien - fixed

Comment: As usual I'm not happy until I get a [solution in K](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153548/69200) that's shorter than the **J** one. That said, can you use the same trick here? Generate permutations of the sorted input string (therefore removing the need to sort the permutated list)?

Comment: Not tried **J** until half an hour ago, but why does `1+A./:'seen'` return 10, but `A./:'speech'` return 545. I was hoping this would be a magical solution.

Comment: @streetster I'm not sure. `A.` is the anagram index (the number of the permutation). I don't know how to account for the repeating symbols in your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

## Tcl, 196 bytes

```
proc p {a p} {if {$a eq {}} {lappend ::p $p} {while {[incr n]<=[llength $a]} {p [lreplace $a $n-1 $n-1] $p[lindex $a $n-1]}}}
p [split $argv ""] ""
puts [expr [lsearch [lsort -unique $p] $argv]+1]
```

Tcl has no built-in method to compute the next lexicographic permutation, so we have to do it ourselves. But wait... it is *shorter* to do it with a simple recursive function that computes *all* possible permutations in any order.

Ungolfed:

```
# Compute all possible permutations of the argument list
# Puts the result in ::all_permutations
proc generate_all_permutations {xs {prefixes ""}} {
  if {$xs eq {}} {
    lappend ::all_permutations $prefixes
  } else {
    while {[incr n] <= [llength $xs]} {
      generate_all_permutations [lreplace $xs $n-1 $n-1] $prefixes[lindex $xs $n-1]
    } 
  }
}

# Get our input as command-line argument, turn it into a list of letters
generate_all_permutations [split $argv ""]

# Sort, remove duplicates, find the original argument, and print its 1-based index
puts [expr [lsearch [lsort -unique $all_permutations] $argv]+1]
```

Comment: I shaved off some bytes: https://tio.run/##NYyxCsMwDET3foUI3kqGrKH5EleDcdTEIBzhOG3A@NtdtaXDHcfT6bLn1iRtHgTcXa2EBxTjpqnUCoWdCMUZxlHAiILXGpig2BB9goi3yTJTXPIKxqHeBSwnEnaelICJ/fA11HfLIc50/jnWWi/a34VDVpiWJ3Qdqi5y5B0snZJ0bieX/PoJW8rQH7qEvzpeB2ytvQE

Comment: More shaving https://tio.run/##NYzBCsIwEETvfsVScq3gtdgvSfcQ07UNLOmSpiqEfHtcFQ8zDG9nJ3tuTdLmQcBNaiXcoRg3jqVWKOxEKM4wDAJGFDzXwATFhugTRLyOlpniklcwDvUuYDmRsPOkBEzsL19Dfbcc4kyvP8da60n7u3DICtPygK5D1UmOvOvQTi75Fc7TJ28pQ3/oDP662Fq78UFv

Comment: Thank you. When I get access to a real computer again I'll update.

Answer (score 2):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>23</s> 18 bytes

**Solution:**

```
1+*&x~/:?x@prm@<x:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/31BbS62iTt/KvsKhoCjXwabCSqm4IDU1OUPp/38A)

**Examples:**

```
1+*&x~/:?x@prm@<x:"seen"
10
1+*&x~/:?x@prm@<x:"blue"
4
```

**Explanation:**

Generate permutations of the indices of the sorted input string, use them to index back into the input string, take the distincts, see where the original string matched, and add one.

```
1+*&x~/:?x@prm@<x: / the solution
                x: / save input string as x
               <   / return indices when sorting x ascending
           prm@    / apply (@) function prm
         x@        / index into x with these permutations
        ?          / distinct (remove duplicates)
    x~/:           / apply match (~) between x and each-right (/:)
   &               / return indexes where true (ie the match)
  *                / take the first one
1+                 / add 1 due to 1-indexing requirement
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 211 bytes

```java
import java.util.*;TreeSet q=new TreeSet();s->{p("",s);return-~q.headSet(s).size();}void p(String p,String s){int l=s.length(),i=0;if(l<1)q.add(p);for(;i<l;p(p+s.charAt(i),s.substring(0,i)+s.substring(++i,l)));}
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##pVLdasIwGL33KT68StYa3XXXwR5gMnB3Yxdp@mnj0jQmXx1Ould3qdMxxkCwhRDOIeeHQ9dyKyeNQ7su3w66do0nWEdOtKSNuMkgftMpPMnIN0ugCqHYEU5U01oaKSNDgEep7X4EoC2hX0qFMO/hkQDFFuS1XUHgWSS7eJ494gIJNrnF9zNi/EIWwBws5HAIk/u9Y@NxGh09Uuvt5HMjKpRlbxO4CPoDo103OjvOGwL3v@u20SW4c0eX/pTd9@VNHoRBu6KK8VTns0wvmbm75Rshy5I5ni0bzzJ9ZzLHXBKEqqR/IKZ5GkRoi3A0Y7NU8@Q3kSQ6NZzHigcA1xZGKwgkKV7HPnUc9FTp5VXy7zH7laGOA/Sj9YAdBwVY7AJhLZqWhIsSMpbVwgrFxoVpccxPz2rxd@8L6oBor1dHWA8Jbx366@WFwRAGpDtEVV2vx/izDZDLAdJClQNmk@fobtQdvgA)

```java
import java.util.*;        // Required import for TreeSet

TreeSet q=new TreeSet();   // Sorted Set on class-level

s->{                       // Method with String parameter and integer return-type
  p("",s);                 //  Save all unique permutations of the String in the sorted set
  return-~q.headSet(s).size();}
                           //  Return the 0-indexed index of the input in the set + 1

void p(String p,String s){ // Separated method with 2 String parameters and no return-type
  int l=s.length(),        //  The length of the String `s`
      i=0;                 //  Index integer, starting at 0
  if(l<1)                  //  If String `s` is empty
    q.add(p);              //   Add `p` to the set
  for(;i<l;                //  Loop from 0 to `l` (exclusive)
    p(                     //   Do a recursive call with:
      p+s.charAt(i),       //    `p` + the character at the current index of `s` as new `p`
      s.substring(0,i)+s.substring(++i,l)));}
                           //    And `s` minus this character as new `s`
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>183</s> 182 bytes

The first answer that run in polynomial time!

```python
a=[*map(ord,input())]
f=lambda x:x and x*f(x-1)or 1
c=[0]*98
for C in a:c[C]+=1
l=len(a)
F=f(l)
for i in c:F//=f(i)
r=1
for x in a:F//=l;l-=1;r+=sum(c[:x])*F;F*=c[x];c[x]-=1
print(r)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYtBC8IgHMXvfgqP6hprdCnlfxoJHYLoKh7MJQnODdvAPv1ydXnwfu/3ps/8GuNhXQ0oNpiJjKnf@TgtM6FUIwfBDI/e4MwzNrHHmTmS65aOCbfIgtprdjoiV2qHfcSGW9XpCloUIDwjMRRJcCTQn@I3xXLZNIV5ilLxNp7/140HEWpoRargvQzEKp41ZVJIBlZlLbYoO5qSjzNJdF1v98v1/AU)

Require the input to be all upper-case, because... it saves a byte.

Full program, takes input from `stdin` and output to `stdout`.

---

Variable names: (sort of ungolfed code)

```python
a : permu
f : factorial
c : count_num
C : char
l : n_num_left
F : factor
r : result
```

Unfortunately, `from math import factorial as f` takes exactly 1 more byte.

---

(Unrelated note: I checked the `` Combinatorica` `` package of Mathematica, nothing useful, including `RankPermutation`)

Comment: That code is really nice.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>105</s> <s>104</s> 103 bytes

```python
f=lambda s:s==s*2or f(s[1:])+sum(f(sorted(s[:s.index(c)]+s[s.index(c)+1:])[::-1])for c in{*s}if c<s[0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7LCsMgEEXX7Ve4U5OmNC10IU1/JLgwPkggMeIYaAn5dqtuuhnOPVwu475hXO0jRtPNYhmUQMCg66C6rx4ZAn3LOK1hW0gKqw9aJcfgOlmlP0RSXkP/T3Vu94w1LacmDUg02b2CYzJIvqC/cRqzhqQRdn5aNL4gDJvTPsMwa4BinNZyzKSFDwVEOYNUpSgEZudTWrCBGLwDex6oeaM9PUnZ48A0/gA)

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 230 bytes

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;void R(string s){int n=1;auto p=s;sort(begin(p),end(p));do if(p==s)cout<<n;while(++n,next_permutation(begin(p),end(p)));}int main(int n,char**a){R(a[1]);}
```

As per my asking, the code definitely need to be executable as-is. The function-only clause is basically rubbish. :-@

Thank you to those who kindly answered the question of what can be cut out for me. In the interest of *valid* code, I’ve avoided the popular GCC-ism of including <bits/stdc++.h>, which I have always considered a bad loophole cheat.

What follows is what remains of my original posting:

---

I am always unsure when using C and C++ what counts towards the byte total. According to [Program, Function, or Snippet?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet) the answer is still vague (as long as it isn’t a snippet, I guess). So I am going with the shortest of the two possibilities.

Here it is ungolfed *with necessary headers, etc:*

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void R( string s )
{
  int n = 1;
  auto p = s;
  sort( begin(p), end(p) );
  do if (p == s) cout << n;
  while (++n, next_permutation( begin(p), end(p) ));
}

int main( int n, char** a )
{
  R( a[1] );
}
```

That golfs down to 230 bytes, a third of that standard boilerplate required by *every* C++ program. (So, I don’t feel too bad not counting it, but as I haven’t ever seen a firm complaint either way, OP will have to tell me which he prefers to satisfy “write a code to take any word as an input and display its rank.”)

I am also unsure if this satisfies “the rank should be output.”

Comment: Uh... AFAIK our rules count necessary (`using namespace std`, `#include <algorithm>`  headers used to define the function in bytes. And... No, `main(){}` is a valid C++ (g++) program at 8 bytes.

Comment: I am not trying to be an obstinate snot, but I see submissions for C and C++ (as well as other languages) _all the time_ that are just a single function. I want a definitive answer. I typically don’t golf in C-languages for this very reason. (And I am happy to regolf.)

Comment: Even in Python, `import math` is often necessary. Let me find the relevant meta...

Comment: @Dúthomhas Those solutions don't require header includes. Basic arithmetic requires no header, and some functions can be implicitly declared and filled in by the linking of the stdlib (like `puts` and `printf`). Your code must compile and run successfully as-is for it to be valid. See: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10085/45941

Comment: @Mego Without declaration of `main` functions can't be run as-is.

Comment: Also in C++ include's are strictly necessary, unlike C.

Comment: @user202729 `main` isn't necessary in a function submission. However, function submissions *are* required to count any additional code needed to run them, aside from standard boilerplate. In the case of C/C++, that standard boilerplate is a `main` function that takes input and calls the function. This is no different from e.g. Python, where `lambda s,r:re.match(r,s)` is not valid, because it needs to be `lambda s,r:re.match(r,s);import re`.

Comment: I am considering asking this on meta, since it is an issue. Two examples found since I posted here: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66481/60291 (show me a C compiler that will turn that into a working program), and https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124243/60291 (no compiler in existence will compile that into a working program, since #defines don't exist until used!). CodeGolf is biased towards esoteric languages like Jelly. I personally only care about competing against other submissions for the same language, but for C and C++, _the playing field is not level_.

Comment: [172 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZYtBCsIwEADvvqLgJWmq4jmNHxGRdLs2gXYTuhsUxLfHevY0h5mBnA8TQK37SDCXEfshCp9YRjDmGC67wpGmhvyCnD1gsxm7@EgqkjTUQfBr23r9Zll/ISt/JXe@6S47tpxWUQNOW551hzRu0HZMTXyo7BxrSEX6nuwzxBmVMdQRvuSecV2KeImJ/nZtP7VWzogQvg "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), <s>113</s> 111 bytes

```
import StdEnv,StdLib
?s=elemIndex s[[]:removeDup(foldr(\a b=sort[insertAt i a x\\x<-b,i<-[0..length x]])[[]]s)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY49C4MwFEX3/oq3qaDSuShSaAfBzTFmiOZpA/mQJEr655sGnC53OPfcRSLTURl@SATFhI5C7cZ6GD1/67NMMYj51rkWJapecwzgCKEPi8qc@Dr2fDWS23xiMLcukURoh9Y/PQhgEKYpNNVciqYi97qWqDf/gUBpkUaoK2gcPUu6Fjog2SwPzGj8Latkm4tVP8TXVzMllqtcb/4)

+3 bytes to handle 1-indexing :/

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 33 bytes (SBCS)

```apl
⎕CY'dfns'
{∪⊃∘(⍵[⍋⍵])¨¨↓pmat≢⍵}⍳⊂
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVFNS8NAEL3nV4y9RKHtD/AqHv049CLiYZJMmpXNbshsKEG8KBStRAQRvHjxJF7FP9Cfsn9EJ6lNexZCsm923nvzJljoUVKjttOfH9@8wSQj4CrKFbOyBmI0oYOIgIyjkhLI5D0EJpKitrOdFev4ZHK4L1zFII8TjZJQbwntB0Hb5x9fDs7CJDUcdvjK3336xa2/e931zfe5bx7kc7G3/Fh@@PlzkaPz9@9SuvbNl1/crESOUBlIKxO7dsLdjcme3G8ZpODnT/@zmBBL3N5kVTzVhExgrCOJiA5SWwIrM9U0ijOUsysFscSOM0CGEEOobQUzW@lEeGWOWtdgiJJO0FlwdUEwGErnAJQRU0zApnBZsYNBWx2vttpy2tXmyqkpOgFR3e3ZdZN2cutpx0HQVrv0fvE@TCX7cJNL/ikT//WERalyCv8AVwWVaxBpYu5vCqI4WyPC0vUA@0MUJz0ZMfwF)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>106</s> 100 bytes

```js
w=>(P=(a,s)=>a[0]?a.map((_,i)=>P(b=[...a],s+b.splice(i,1))):P[s]=P[s]||++k)[P([...w].sort(),k=''),w]
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

w=>(P=(a,s)=>a[0]?a.map((_,i)=>P(b=[...a],s+b.splice(i,1))):P[s]=P[s]||++k)[P([...w].sort(),k=''),w]

console.log(f("prime"))  // 94
console.log(f("super"))  // 93
console.log(f("bless"))  // 4
console.log(f("speech")) // 354
console.log(f("earth"))  // 28
console.log(f("a"))      // 1
console.log(f("abcd"))   // 1
console.log(f("baa"))    // 3
```

#### How?

**P()** is our recursive permutation function. But the encompassing object of **P** is also used to store the ranks of the permutations.

```js
P = (a, s) =>               // given an array of letters a[] and a string s
  a[0] ?                    // if a[] is not empty:
    a.map((_, i) =>         //   for each entry at position i in a[]:
      P(                    //     do a recursive call to P() with:
        b = [...a],         //       a copy b[] of a[], with a[i] removed
        s + b.splice(i, 1)  //       the extracted letter appended to s
      )                     //     end of recursive call
    )                       //   end of map()
  :                         // else:
    P[s] = P[s] || ++k      //   if P[s] is not already defined, set it to ++k
```

The wrapping code now reads as:

```js
w =>                        // given the input word w
  P[                        // return the permutation rank for w
    P(                      //   initial call to P() with:
      [...w].sort(),        //     the lexicographically sorted letters of w
      k = ''                //     s = k = '' (k is then coerced to a number)
    ),                      //   end of call
    w                       //   actual index used to read P[]
  ]                         // end of access to P[]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 49 bytes

```ruby
->w{c=w.chars
1+c.sort.permutation.uniq.index(c)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XctBDoIwFATQPadocKMxNMFqogu4iHHRfj6hiUD9bYPGePZKhHbh7OZlhrx6hbYKRT29oZo4dJJsVu6B25EcN0i9d9LpceB@0A@uhwafW9h9gmHtNTeke8xvbMOKml2O2Q@tn28JxYLqjtZGjEODCF1EcVoZJbmkh/OCMkK5dgXNHymZRoLNCV8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 98 + 3 (`-pF`) = 101 bytes

```perl
$"=',';@a=grep{++$k{$_}<=1&&"@F"eq join$",sort/./g}sort glob"{@F}"x(@F=sort@F);1while!/$a[$\++]/}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcjBCsIgGADgV1kiW@E2t8NOS/DkrSeoiBU/zpJpOigQX70/dvv4PAQ7IFIiqroa5SR0AJ8Yo69Eb/ko@rIkUhF4F09nFkrq6MLKW67zhkJbdydJqky@e6nEdlIdxv4zGws7TqczvTB25TkhRg/wmH/Or8YtEZvT0HZ9h41Xfw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 43 bytes

```matlab
@(s)find(all(unique(perms(s),'rows')==s,2))
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##LcvBCoAgDMbxey/iBuGhu9CrLJskmJrLenwT8rQff74le9PDzRmtdVtB0Pm4A4UANfqrMmQup/Q@q5JeUWiMzAtic6By8ScrnDql9t3PLbDIqJnZHr@Zyj1I42x2Hy/UU/sA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 53 bytes

```
{1+first :k,$_,.comb.permutations».join.unique.sort}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcxNDoIwEAbQq3whxI2kiRsXKlyFTHEaqvTHTrsghJO582KV3Vu9yGm5VrfiZNDX7XI2NknG7d21Y6em4LSKnFzJlG3w8vuqV7BeFW8/hZWElPcqtKJpR/QDNoN23BuYkPDQS2EIs0dM1h0sRwW9sAgkMk8zmFKeQSA9PaGJhnv9Aw)

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 275 bytes

```powershell
param($s)function n($a){if($a-eq1){return}0..($a-1)|%{n($a-1);if($a-eq2){$b.ToString()}$p=($j-$a);[char]$t=$b[$p];for($z=($p+1);$z-lt$j;$z++){$b[($z-1)]=$b[$z]}$b[($z-1)]=$t}}if($s.length-eq1){1;exit}$b=New-Object Text.StringBuilder $s;(n($j=$s.length)|sort -u).indexOf($s)+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BboMwEER/hcNWsYVslV4Rl35Ac2huiAOQJRg5htqLgiD@dtcUteppVzOzb2caH2hdj1qHMNW2vjNwvJtNS2o0iWFQ8011cQj8yvhmkWZr/KuUu5Tx58tmji3/Tb3xDRp5GT/JKnNj3MNUMBhEJOVl29e2AiqgKWGq8m60DNZoT2kkwCo0wRBnmu6QMnqRXP2k18r/V8j7/aGTGs2N@qNdluOiKOaKD3yIczNgS8kFF5JHmfdZ6SvaBFzOYu2h@LvnTzdaSsTMpTJXXM47m6dZCOHU1nT6Bg)

So, this is a bloody mess.

*PowerShell doesn't have any permutations built-in, so this code uses the algorithm from [here](https://learn-powershell.net/2013/02/21/fun-with-powershell-and-permutations/) (golfed heavily), which is available under the Microsoft Limited Public License ([Exhibit B](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/cc300389.aspx#P) on this licensing page).*

The program takes input `$s` as a string, then the actual program starts with `$b=New-Object ...`. We're constructing a new [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) object, which is (essentially) a mutable string of characters. This will allow us to handle the permutations more easily. We then call the function `n` (setting `$j` along the way to be the length of the input string), `sort` with the `-u`nique flag the output, take the `.indexOf()` to find the input string, and add `1` because PowerShell is zero-indexed.

The function is the main part of the program. It takes as input a number, and will each iteration count down until we reach `1` (i.e., a single letter). The rest of the function essentially recursively calls the function as well as takes the current letter and iterates it through every position.

There's a single bit of additional logic `if($s.length-eq1){1;exit}` to account for input strings of length `1` due to how the permutations function works.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

```
ĐᒆỤ≥Ʃ
```

Explanation:

```
            Implicit input
Đ           Duplicate input
 ᒆ         Get list of all permutations of input
  Ụ         Get unique permutations
   ≥        Does each permutation come before or is equal to the input?
    Ʃ       Sum of result of previous step (converts booleans to ints)
```

[<s>Try it online!</s>](https://tio.run/##ARoA5f9weXT//8SQ4ZKG4buk4omlxqn//3NwZWVjaA)